# Configure sSMTP with Gmail, in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: proxy, gmail, smtp

I am trying to get my hands on a good command line email tool for Ubuntu so that I can send simple emails may be even attach files through the terminal or simple bash scripts. My *ssmtp.conf* file looks something like this right now:

```
#
# Config file for sSMTP sendmail
#
# The person who gets all mail for userids < 1000
# Make this empty to disable rewriting.
root=myusername@gmail.com

# The place where the mail goes. The actual machine name is required no 
# MX records are consulted. Commonly mailhosts are named mail.domain.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587

# Where will the mail seem to come from?
rewriteDomain=gmail.com

# The full hostname
hostname=myusername@gmail.com
AuthUser=myusername
AuthPass=mypassword
UseSTARTTLS=YES 
# Are users allowed to set their own From: address?
# YES - Allow the user to specify their own From: address
# NO - Use the system generated From: address
FromLineOverride=YES
```

I also added alias in the *revaliases* file as follows:

```
root:myusername@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
localusername:myusername@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
```

I am behind a proxy server which works when i set an automatic proxy configuration URL and my system proxy settings are set according to the automatic proxy configuration URL.

However when I run sSMTP from terminal using:

```
sudo ssmtp someone@example.com
hello world
```

Then pressing ctrl+d, I get:

```
ssmtp: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587
```

*The title is the question.*

Answer (score 3):

> mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:465

The port is wrong. Your aliases need updating too.

Gmail only really allows SSL emails from remote hosts, other connections usually don't work. Enable SSL and use port 465.

If that doesn't work verify connectivity with telnet:

`telnet smtp.gmail.com:465` it should work, and return gibberish.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @coteyr, I changed the port to 465 but get this error `Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:465  ` and I tried `telnet smtp.gmail.com ` it says  **network unreachable**  . So i think it is a connectivity issue. Am i missing some certificates that need to be installed or is the proxy? how do i resolve it?

Comment: it is possible that your network configuration does not allow any traffic that does not go though the proxy. I have seen a few setups like that. Network Unreachable means that it can't get to smtp.gmail.com at all, and has nothing to do with SMTP or proxy. Check your default route, and try `tracert smtp.gmail.com` You may need to install it.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested the upper combination and the port is correct. Definitely, 587 is a correct port, I selected this value for my settings and work.

Probably the problem here is due to the existence of an outgoing rule into the firewall, or a new limitation of the security policy of gmail. You have to go to https://myaccount.google.com and check "Access for less secure apps": it must allowed, it's disallowed by default.